# Count of active employees between two date columns, by department

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to imitate [this report](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-showcase/agile-analytics-hr-analytics/) (page 3) where it slices active headcount and all the other metrics (1) by date and (2) by department.

My data looks like this (with relationships, of course):

| ID | Name | DEPID | Hired Date | Terminated Date | Terminated (Y/N) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2 | 1/1/2019 | 2020/12/31 | Y |
| 2 | Jane | 2 | 1/3/2018 | 2019/07/26 | Y |
| 3 | Jack | 1 | 1/5/2022 | null | N |

Using the [following measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70739331/show-count-and-filter-active-employees-based-on-date-slicer), I was able to extract total number of employees by date, but I wasn't able to filter by department:

```
CountOfActive = 
var _selectedDate = MAX('Calendar'[Date])
return
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'); filter(ALL('Table'); Table[HIREDDATE] <= VALUE(_selectedDate) && (Table[TERMINATEDDATE] >= VALUE(_selectedDate) || ISBLANK(Table[TERMINATEDDATE]))))
```

My ideal output is something like the following (where I'll create a table for each department and list the number of active employees, then join them to my department key table afterwards so I can slice them):

| Date | Count of Active Employees | Department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019/1/1 | 3 | Retail |
| 2019/1/2 | 3 | Retail |
| 2019/1/3 | 4 | Retail |
| ... | ... | ... |

The "Date" column would be a calendar table built with CALENDAR().

What should I do to achieve the last table based on the data I have?

My relationship schema looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6HG9.jpg).

Comment: which 'Date' is the first column ? what is the source?

Comment: Edited. It would be a calendar table built with CALENDAR().

Comment: Why do you use semicolon in your DAX code ? This is not excel. Dialect is always the same, separator as comma(,).

Comment: Remove that VALUE() function in your DAX Code. There is already only one scalar value returned by aggregate MAX function. What do you expect the VALUE() to do for you there ?

Answer (score 1):

try this : 'Table 2' is your Calendar Table which is also a slicer on the visual.

Make sure that your Calendar Table's Date has a relation with the Hired Date and also the relation between the Department Table

[image: relations]

```
Count of Emp =
VAR _latest =
    MAX ( 'Table 2'[Date] )
VAR _from =
    MIN ( 'Table 2'[Date] )
VAR _dept =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Department[Department] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTX ( 'Table', 'Table'[ID ] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Table' ),
            'Table'[Terminated Date ] >= _from
                && 'Table'[Hired Date ] <= _from
                && 'Table'[Terminated (Y/N)] = "Y"
                && RELATED ( Department[Department] ) = _dept
        )
    )
        + CALCULATE (
            COUNTX ( 'Table', 'Table'[ID ] ),
            FILTER (
                ALL ( 'Table' ),
                'Table'[Terminated (Y/N)] = "N"
                    && 'Table'[Hired Date ] <= _from
                    && RELATED ( Department[Department] ) = _dept
            )
        )
```

[image: Result]

Comment: @sokhymi did this work on your data?

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. It showed incorrect results where it said my organization has a total of 49 employees (while it ought to be around 1500), and it doesn't show all departments. I've updated my post with a view of the relationship model.

Comment: @sokhymi please provide more sample data to check what is wrong with the code. For the given data sample data, it works normally.

Comment: Hi, I rephrased the question here so (hopefully) it's more understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73725274/count-of-active-rows-between-two-dates-sliced-by-department